# Getting Mouse Coordinates of each click

Tags: javascript, mouse, coordinates

I have the following script. I need to get the coordinates of each mouse click coordinates sent to my email at the end of the loop of the images. Can someone please help me with this? I am very new in this, and am trying to implement some of my memory tasks (that I have written in Matlab before) for online. Any help will be much appreciated.

here's my script:

```
<head>
<title>Practice2</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="MemStyle.CSS">
<script type = "text/javascript">        
var x=0;
function changeImage() 
{
if (x == images.length){
return;      
}

document.getElementById("img").src=images[x]
x++;
}

var images =  ["S2b.jpg", "S3b.jpg", "S4b.jpg", "S5b.jpg", "S1b.jpg"];       

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="MemImg">
<button onclick="changeImage()" >
<img id="img"  width="700px" height="700px" >
</button>   
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So all you need is an event handler, learn how the event object works, what `event.pageX` does, how you send that to the server with ajax, how you set up a mail server, and how you'd send email from the webserver. And you want us to code that for you ?

Comment: No Sorry I only need the mouse coordinates. Everything else is set up! Sorry if this wasnt clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get mouse Coordinates with very simple math. 
Are you going to attach event handler to image tag? If that is the case, you can copy below code.
I understand you would be very frustrated if you don't have understanding of 
javascript events, DOM model, etc. It is not that hard to understand if you 
spend just some effort though. 
I am just assuming the basse point (0,0) would be where the image tag is located.
(if image tag located at (34,34), I assuming that (34,34) would be (0,0))

```
<script>
    function sendMouseCoodinate(evt){
       //if you just want send absolute moouseCoodinate, send evt.clientX, evt.clientY
       // sendToMyMail(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
       //or you can send relative mouseCoodinate of image tag.
       var coodinateX = parseInt(evt.clientX) - this.getBoundingClientRect().left;
       var coodinateY = parseInt(evt.clientY) - this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
       // here you can send coodinateX, coodianteY value to your mail server

     }
     window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
         document.getElementById("imgArea").addEventListener("mousedown", sendMouseCoodinate,false);
     });
</script>
<img id="imgArea">
```